# bash sorting multiple duplicate strings in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I have file like below:

```
Personname:Mark
Hobby:chess
Hobby:tennis
Personname:Tom
Hobby:swimming
Hobby:badminton
Hobby:boxing
Hobby:music
Personname:Nick
Hobby:swimming
Personname:fabio
Hobby:swimming
Hobby:badminton
Hobby:boxing
Hobby:music
```

---

What I need is below format:

```
Mark,chess,tennis
Tom,swimming,badminton,badminton,boxing,music
Nick,swimming
fabio,swimming,badminton,badminton,boxing,music
```

I tried with "tr", while but not able to figure out the correct logic because of duplicate string names. Can you advice?

Answer (score 3):

Doing the same as Oli suggested with sh instead of awk:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=:
while read key value; do
    if [ "$key" = "Personname" ]; then
        printf "\n%s" $value
    else
        printf ",%s" $value
    fi
done < data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly trivially with an `awk`. This just looks at each line on its own. If it's a name, we stick a newline in and print the name, if it's not, we stick a comma in (without a newline) and print the hobby.

```
$ awk -F: '$1=="Personname" {printf("\n%s", $2)} $1=="Hobby" {printf(",%s", $2)}' data 

Mark,chess,tennis
Tom,swimming,badminton,boxing,music
Nick,swimming
fabio,swimming,badminton,boxing,music
```

αғsнιη's suggestion in the comments switches the logic around to use a ternary condition to decide what string to write. It's neat but I'd explicitly check we were looking at a Personname or Hobby line and not a blank one or not a Hobby called Personname. Something like this should do it:

```
awk -F: '{printf $1=="Personname" ? "\n"$2 : $1=="Hobby" ? ","$2 : ""}' data
```

Comment: a suggestion: `awk -F: '{printf /Personname/? "\n"$2:","$2}' data`

Comment: That's pretty neat (I didn't know you could inline ternary constructs like that in awk) but what if somebody's hobby is Personname or there's a blank line. I like the idea but you need to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Two issues with above 1) creates blank line at top 2) there is no new line at end, which is causing difficulty to use "sort"